# Serverside code proceeds even when validation fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

If the 2 passwords provided upon registering an account don't match, the validation catches this, and tells the user that they don't match. But the user still getting created. The same goes if the password they provide is less than 6 characters. Must one manually tell the system not to proceed if the validation fails? And if so, how?

My model looks like this:

```
  [Display(Name ="Your Email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="You must provide a valid Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Select a user name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name="User name")]
    public string nickName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Select a password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name="Password")]
    [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage="The password must be at least 6 characters long")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Type your password again")]
    [Display(Name="Confirm password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("password", ErrorMessage="The two passwords do not match")]
    public string confirmPassword { get; set; }
```

The view looks like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RegisterNewUser", "RegisterUser", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updaterDiv" }))
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nickName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nickName, new { @class = "RegisterControls" })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nickName)
        <br /><br />

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.email, new { @class = "RegisterControls" })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email)
        <br /><br />

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password)
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.password, new { @class = "RegisterControls", id = "firstPassword" })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password)
        <br /><br />

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.confirmPassword)
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.confirmPassword, new { @class = "RegisterControls" })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.confirmPassword)
        <br /><br /><br />
        <hr style="color: #D5E0EE; border: solid; border-style: double;" />

        <input type="submit" value="Create account" class="actionButtons" />
        <br /><br />
        <p style="color: red">@ViewBag.DeniedMsg</p>
```

And Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterNewUser(RegisteredUsersModel registerUserModel)
    {
        ViewBag.Header = "Register";
        string msg = "";

        if (!users.RegisterUser(registerUserModel.nickName, registerUserModel.email, registerUserModel.password))
        {
            msg = "The provided email already exists";
        }

        ViewBag.DeniedMsg = msg;
        return PartialView("_Register");            
    }
```

Another problem I have, is that the user is created twice, so there is two of him in the database. Can anyone see a problem regarding this in my code? Or perhaps I might have to open a separate ticket for this problem

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are using validation, controller does not do automatically with it. You need to use ModelState.IsValid check to find out if your validation passed or not:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegisterNewUser(RegisteredUsersModel registerUserModel)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // this block is executed only when validation succeeds
        ViewBag.Header = "Register";
        string msg = "";

        if (!users.RegisterUser(registerUserModel.nickName, registerUserModel.email, registerUserModel.password))
        {
            msg = "The provided email already exists";
        }

        ViewBag.DeniedMsg = msg;
        return PartialView("_Register");            
    }

    // this code is executed only when validation fails
    return View(RegisteredUsersModel);    // or do something else, depending on your logic
}
```